# PHP/Java Bridge Error

Tags: php-java-bridge

I am trying to connect the PHP with Java with the PHP/Java Bridge library. But I am facing an error as given below.

Please check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What happened when you followed the advice given in the error message?

Comment: I have try to run the command manually php-cgi -b .. but it's give me error but it working with php-cgi -S command

Answer (score 0):

By default, the phpjavabridge servlet try to connect to a php-cgi daemon. It can be easily fixed, either by starting one of the bundled php-cgi (found in WEB_INF/cgi, follow the error message) or modify the configuration in the web.xml (see [an example here](https://github.com/belgattitude/php-java-bridge/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)) to provide your system php-cgi path. Repackage and redeploy your war file.

That said, if you want to use Java from PHP (and not PHP from Java), you don't need a php-cgi daemon. My recommendation, have a look to the following project: http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/. This is a reworked version focusing on PHP -> Java integration.

Feel free to open issues on https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha